# suppress keyboard in iphone UiWebViews

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

I have an app that uses UiWebViews, and I need to not show the keyboard for a text field within such a view.  I provide my own buttons that insert the limited sorts of text the field allows, but I also need to allow pasting (I will filter what gets pasted) and adjusting the cursor position.  Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this can't be done, I've researched it further and that's pretty clear.  I don't want to accept a wrong answer, so I figured I'd just answer this myself and say: can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want the textField do normal things except the showing keyboard action, you could subclass `UITextField` and overwrite the `touchesBegan/Moved/Ended`, just call super `touchesBegan/Moved/Ended` and add additional code which would hide the keyboard, if you have a reference to the keyboard ( you may figure it out urself how-to ), call the method : `[keyboard resignFirstResponder]`, you may try to Category the `UITextField` class so you would have the reference to the keyboard ( if it's private ) - but not recommended because categorying may break our project design, but if you just need it for the only purpose, give it a try. Hope it helps.